# Single dynamic values submitted through one form

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I am using Jquery UI Selectable.  The user has the option to dynamically add new list items to the original setup.

I would like to include a 'clear' button that will give the user the ability to clear each individual item they created by clicking on an X input submit (img).

HTML (php)

```
    if ($this->session->userdata('inactivefilter') == true) {
            $inactivefilter = $this->session->userdata('inactivefilter');
            $i=0;
            foreach ($inactivefilter as $filter)
                {
                    $filterdash = implode('-', explode(' ', $filter));
                    echo "<li class='ui-state-default' id='$filterdash'>$filter</li>";
                    echo "<div id=clear>
                            <form method='POST' action='".base_url()."main/clear_filter'>
                                <input type='image' name='filtervalue' value='$i' src='".base_url()."img/board/icons/clear.png'></input>
                            </form>
                          </div>";
                    $i++;
                }
        }
```

This is where the list is created.  specifically the clear_filter action form.

Clear_filter currently 'attempts' to grab the value of '$i' but I don't know how to pass that correctly.

here is the controller:

```
    public function clear_filter()
    {
        $i = $_POST['filtervalue'];
        $this->thread_model->clear_filter($i);
    }
```

I'll omit the clear_filter model due to its irrelevance to the problem.

Essentially, I just need $i to be picked up based on whatever value is clicked on in the dynamic form on the actual page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like I just had things a bit backwards.

The code was more or less correct.

For Codeigniter, you catch the passed input `value=$i` by using the `name ="filtervalue"`

Change the controller code to :

`$i = $this->input->post('filtervalue');`

and $i is set to whatever value was clicked on.